# escape Shell string node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, escaping

So i am trying to run a `shell` command from my `node.js script`:

```
var child = exec('mysqldump -u "'+dbConfig.user+'" --password="' + dbConfig.password + '" --single-transaction ' + dbConfig.database + ' > ' + dumpFilePath)
```

Now this is all well and fine however the `password` can contain special characters that would break the command.

I have been looking into this node module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/shell-escape

However one of its issue is that it cant parse `=` sign. which makes the package useless to the above statement.

So my question is how can i safely escape the password field?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can escape the password safely with single quotes:

```
var child = exec('mysqldump -u ' + dbConfig.user + ' --password=\'' + dbConfig.password + '\' --single-transaction ' + dbConfig.database + ' > ' + dumpFilePath)
```

Comment: will this take into account special characters such as {/#$£ ect

Comment: Yes it will ([strong quoting](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting?do=show#strong_quoting)).

Comment: I'm not sure it can be considered safe. What if the user or password contains a single quote?